# How to solve "unable to connect to sql server database"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using asp.net c# mvc with entity framework to build an website. And I need to create reset password for this and i have coded all the relevant parts properly as i guessed. But when i'm executing it will give me an exception called "**unable to connect to sql server database**" as follows.

[image]

Here is my Web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TheFoodyContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TheFoodyModel.csdl|res://*/TheFoodyModel.ssdl|res://*/TheFoodyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-NJOQTOK;initial catalog=TheFoody;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

   <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add 
      name="SqlProvider" 
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
      connectionStringName="TheFoodyContext"
      applicationName="/"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      requiresUniqueEmail="true"
      passwordFormat="Hashed" />
  </providers>
</membership>

  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\email"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

</configuration>
```

And i'm very new to this environment and don't know how to fix this exception.

Comment: check connection string

Comment: You are using Integrated security in your ConnectionString, are you sure your server support it?

Comment: Yes. Its worked for others. So for only this it didnt work.

Comment: If it works for others, make sure when you open SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) and using your account you can connect to server. If so then check if the database is visible on the left list.

Comment: Yes. I can connect to server and database is visible on the left side as well

Comment: Check your connectionstring with this website: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 as the SQL client. But the connection string that it is providing is little bit difference than the connection string that i have used in visual studio. But for other part (like register,login etc.) that difference didnt affect like this.

Comment: I have added membership provider configured to my we.config. But now it gives me an error "An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax."